# De obfuscation not working with android studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proguard

I have my code obfuscated with proguard that runs when a release version is build and during the publish of the APK in the play console, I upload the mapping.txt file in "Vitals" section.

When an exception raises I can read clear code in stacktraces (in crashlytics and in Play console).

With previous version of Android studio (<= 2.3.3) all works regulary, now after the upgrade to Android studio 3.0 the same process will not de obfuscate stacktraces anymore.

I came across the migration of gradle plugin introducing the needed modifies

build.gradle (app):

```
    flavorDimensions "mode"
        productFlavors {
        full {
        dimension "mode"
        }
    }
    ...
    buildTypes {
    release {
        multiDexEnabled true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    debug {
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        versionNameSuffix "-DEBUG"
        }
    }
```

What's wrong in the configuration?
The mapping.txt file is correctly uploaded and accepted by Play Console.
Any hint?

Answer (score -2):

It's new in android, when you upload the mapping file, it Deobfuscate your code so you can understand the stack trace. This is the [documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6295281) link, it says:

> If you use ProGuard to optimize and obfuscate your APK files, you can
>   upload a ProGuard mapping file for each version of your app on the
>   Play Console to deobfuscate your crash stack traces and help you
>   better analyze your app's crashes.

Comment: As you can read the question, I wrote that the process works on android studio 2.3 but not in 3.0.

Comment: Have you had any luck so far with this issue?